# How to manage static files from Django 1.8 to Django 1.10

Tags: django, django-templates

I have troubles with upgrading my project from Django 1.8 to Django 1.10: static files are not loaded anymore.

My template looks like this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
...
    <link href="{%static 'file.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
...
```

Then in my file settings.py, I have 'django.contrib.staticfiles' as an installed app. DEBUG is set to True, and I have:

```
STATIC_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/'), "./", ]
```

But when the html is produced, it is like the %static has no effect anymore. It is replaced by the empty string (the same works fine with Django 1.8, where the %static is replaced by the content of STATIC_URL). Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you added the Update the urls.py(mainproject/urls.py), once you made the chnages run the `python manage.py collectstatic` command.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

settings.py
===================
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
def root(folder):
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), '..',folder)

STATIC_ROOT = root('staticstorage')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    root('static'),
)
```

Comment: Thanks, actually only the line: STATIC_URL = '/static/' was useful. It is weird, but when I write something like STATIC_URL='c:/toto/static', it is counted as an empty string, but not if I write for instance '/toto/static'. Maybe the ':' character screw things a bit.

Comment: Also in this case the difference is not between Django1.8 and Django 1.10, but between Linux (where Django 1.8 is installed) and Windows (where Django 1.10 is installed)

Comment: I actually got trapped by the cache system of my browser : I do need all the lines of the settings.py file, but I do not understand why is that.